# Ash shell (busybox), check file extension?

Tags: shell, busybox

I'm porting a script from bash to the busybox shell, ash - how can I check what file extension a file has (and strip that extension to get a generate a directory name) ?

The bash code fragment looks like this:

> ```
> if [[ "$filename" =~ '\.tar\.gz' ]]; then
>     tar -xzf "$filename"
>     dirname="${filename::${#filename}-7}"
> elif  [[ "$filename" =~ '\.tar\.bz2' ]]; then
>     tar -xjf "$filename"
>     dirname="${filename::${#filename}-8}"
> elif  [[ "$filename" =~ '\.tar\.xz' ]]; then
>     xzcat "$filename" | tar -x
>     dirname="${filename::${#filename}-7}"
> else
>     echo "Unknown extension for file: ${filename}" >&2
>     exit 1
> ```

On running the script it contains I get output showing that the code to check the extension is not recognised:

> Unknown extension for file: zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `case`. Use `basename` to remove the extension (which I find cleaner then `${var::}` expansion anyway).

```
case "$filename" in
*.tar.gz)
    tar something
    dirname=$(basename "$filename" .tar.gz)
    ;;
*.tar.bz2)
    tar something
    dirname=$(basename "$filename" .tar.gz2)
    ;;
# and so on
esac
```

Comment: Since you've already matched a specific extension, you can use, e.g., `${filename%.tar.gz}` instead of `basename`. (The original script isn't stripping the leading directories from the path, as `basename` will do.)

Comment: But +1 for using `case` where pattern matching will suffice (as it does in this situation).

Comment: Nice!  I'd forgotten about basename.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `expr` command for regular expression matching, and the `%` operator to strip a known suffix. `expr` implicitly anchors all regular expressions to the beginning of the string, so you'll need to start each one with `.*` to match a suffix. `expr` also writes the number of characters matched to standard output, but you probably don't care to see that.

```
if expr "$filename" : '.*\.tar\.gz' > /dev/null; then
    tar -xzf "$filename"
    dirname="${filename%.tar.gz}"
elif expr "$filename" : '.*\.tar\.bz2' > /dev/null; then
    tar -xjf "$filename"
    dirname="${filename%.tar.gz}"
elif expr "$filename" : '.*\.tar\.xz' > /dev/null; then
    xzcat "$filename" | tar -x
    dirname="${filename%.tar.zx}"
else
    echo "Unknown extension for file: ${filename}" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: This is interesting, I haven't seen expr before.

Comment: It's rarely needed. It also performs integer arithmetic, but that function has been entirely superseded by the arithmetic expression `$((...))`. The only need it fills in POSIX environment is regular-expression matching.